# close multiple websockets connections when option selected

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, connection

I have a textbox where user can start typing letters. If there are relative words in the database , they appear in a `dropdown` below the textbox.

To search the database and bring back results, I use websockets (nodejs 0.10.12 and javascript)

So the code is like so

```
//something is typed , so call the function, to send data and make query
<input id="typename" type="text"  onKeyUp="lookup();" >


//this is where I send data and get back results
function lookup(){
  var so=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");

  so.onerror=function (evt) {alert('Error');}

  so.onopen=function(){
     so.send(document.getElementById("typename").value) 
  }

  so.onmessage = function (evt) {
      var received_msg = evt.data;
      var packet = JSON.parse(received_msg);
      so.close();   
      //feed results to dropdown.....
  }

}
```

This translates to multiple connections open and close as user types.

Even if the user picks something from the dropdown list, the connections, still open and close in the background. Because If I typed for example 4 letters, the open/close will be 4.

If I choose right away what I want, there are still 2 or 3 connections in the background, opening and closing. Which they still feed results. Which means, that actually, dont let me pick what I want. I have to pick it over and over again. (Dropdown flickers) And if I edit it and want to save it back to the db, I cant, because there are still connections running, so I cant open a new one to save it. The code waits...

How can I do something like

```
<select id="listout" size="5"  onChange="so.close();"  >  </select>
```

to stop connections running in the background? The above does not work. Even if I set the `so` to be global or not global. Does not work because I can see multiple connections opening at the same time, but not closing. I have to refresh the page so they can all close.

Any advise?

How can I close all connections, when something is changed on the dropdown(= user picked something)?

Thanks in advance

PS My apologies for the huge intro. Thought will help you to better understand the problem, or offer alternatives

Answer (score 0):

To close opened connections you need save pointers on them when you create them, 
for example:

```
//global variable for store opened connections
var aPoolWSConections = []

function lookup(){
    var so=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");
    //
    // your code here
    //
    // at the end
    aPoolWSConections.push(so);
}
```

Implement a function that will close the connection.

```
function closePoolWSConections(){
    var iSo = aPoolWSConections.length;
    while(iSo--){
        aPoolWSConections[iSo].close();
    }
    aPoolWSConections = [];
}
```

Call a function in necessary time.

```
<select id="listout" size="5"  onChange="closePoolWSConections();"  >  </select>
```

But I would not recommend you to open many connections for your application is sufficient one websocket connection.

```
//Create one global WS connection
var so = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");

so.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    var packet = JSON.parse(received_msg);
    //feed results to dropdown.....
}

function lookup(){
    //maybe should check if it still open
    so.send(document.getElementById("typename").value);
}

//and you can use something like
<select id="listout" size="5"  onChange="so.close();"  >  </select>
```